# Admob for Windowsphone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, admob

white Monetizing a new app

I found out theres no more support for windows phone in Google Admob..

is there any way of using Google admob with my WP8.1 application..

```
note: its a cordova app basically
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "basically"? Is it cordova or not?
In native WP8.1 there is no chance to use Google Admob because Google does not support it.

If you have WP8.1 XAML Application use MS Advertising SDK.